# I'm trying to do a basic crop and send it off to s3, but I'm having trouble converting between image types?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rmagick

Essentially, I have an image url that I extracted from the avatar preview element using jquery. I want to use Rmagick to do a basic cropper and then send it off to s3.

In my controller, I receive a post request with the parameter of the image source from the avatar preview element. This imageurl is passed to my model Uploader.crop

```
Uploader.crop does the rmagick stuff. The steps are convert from imageurl to tempfile using open(fileurl). Reading that file into rmagick's .from_blob method. Doing the cropping actions to it using this format. Lastly, I want to re-convert it and toss into my self.upload method which does the uploading. The parameters are tempfile, but I'm getting an error saying that the file I'm tossing to self.upload in my Uploader model is NOT an appropriate file. 


Here's my Uploader model containing my cropper method and my upload method.

# -*- encoding : utf-8 -*-
class Uploader
  class << self

    def crop(name, tmpfile, bucket)

      image =  Magick::ImageList.new
      urlimage = open(tmpfile)

      image.from_blob(urlimage.read)

      image.format = "jpeg"

      image.write("profile.jpeg")

      image.crop_resized!(120, 120, Magick::CenterGravity)

      self.upload(name, image, "buckets32")

    end 

    def upload(name, tmpfile, bucket)
      #byebug

      service = S3::Service.new(  access_key_id:      "abdefghijklm",
                                  secret_access_key:  "abdefghijklm" )
      bucket      = service.buckets.find("buckets32")

      new_object  = bucket.objects.build(name)
      new_object.content = tmpfile
      new_object.save
    end
  end
end
```